# SQL query to list head blockers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to query a database either by sql query or C# to get me a list or datatable of head blockers currently locking up the database?

Comment: Have you tried doing a google search with your post title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use the following SQL, replacing *'MyDatabaseName'* with either; the *name* of your database, or the value, *NULL*.

```
DECLARE
    @Database NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'MyDatabaseName'

SELECT
   s.login_name AS [Login]
   , ISNULL(db_name(p.dbid), N'') AS [Database]
   , ISNULL(t.task_state, N'') AS [Task State]
   , ISNULL(r.command, N'') AS [Command]
   , s.cpu_time AS [Total CPU (ms)]
   , (s.reads + s.writes) * 8 / 1024 AS [Total Physical I/O (MB)]
   , s.memory_usage * 8192 / 1024 AS [Memory Use (KB)]
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_sessions AS s 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests AS r ON (s.session_id = r.session_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_os_tasks AS t ON (r.session_id = t.session_id AND r.request_id = t.request_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests AS r2 ON (s.session_id = r2.blocking_session_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.sysprocesses AS p ON (s.session_id = p.spid)
WHERE
    r2.session_id IS NOT NULL 
    AND (r.blocking_session_id = 0 OR r.session_id IS NULL)
    AND (@Database IS NULL OR ISNULL(db_name(p.dbid), N'') = @Database)
ORDER BY 
    s.cpu_time DESC
```

*Note: A value of NULL will check all databases within that server.*